# Error when using the powf() function in C

Tags: c

I wrote this C code to find the value for 3 squared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main( void )
{
    float a;
    a = powf( 3, 2 );
    printf( "\n%f\n", a );
    return 0;
}
```

I get the warning `implicit declaration of function 'powf'` even with `math.h` library included and `-lm` in the terminal command:

```
gcc -o test.exe -ansi -Wall test.c -lm
```

My gcc version is 4.2.2 if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`powf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is added in C99. Option [`-ansi`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) is equivalent to `-std=c89`. You need to use `-std=c99` flag.

```
gcc -o test.exe -std=c99 -Wall test.c -lm
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `-ansi` parameter. This is equivalent to `-std=c90`.

As the [man page for powf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/powf) states, you need to use `-std=c99`